# PowerPoint addin unable to call getAccessToken

Tags: office-js

I have an Office addin that works in Word and Excel.  In PowerPoint when I call OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() I receive no response but do see the following error printed to the console.

If I use the beta version of Office.js then everything works fine.

I am using Office Online on Win 10.  Browsers: Chrome and Brave

```
{name: "Internal Error", message: "An internal error has occurred.", code: 5001}
```

#### Update

Today I no longer see the 'Internal Error'  getAccessToken still does not respond (never enters 'then' or 'catch') and I eventually see the below in the console.  Actually I should say it now *sometimes* responds.  I have opened some presentations and it works and keeps working, others it never responds, mostly it never responds.

```
SendShuttingDownRequest: https://auc-powerpoint.officeapps.live.com/pops/RoamingServiceHandler.ashx?action=savePPTSlideLastViewedMetadata&WOPIsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fcmofficedev%2Dmy%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fpersonal%2Fdchurchland%5Fcmofficedev%5Fonmicrosoft%5Fcom%2F%5Fvti%5Fbin%2Fwopi%2Eashx%2Ffiles%2F55f2093742e349d99254631b51f58e99&access_token=eyJ...; requestApi: f
```

I an running Word, Excel and PowerPoint out of the same manifest.

I do have a catch but I never get into the catch.

```js
((global as any).OfficeRuntime.auth as any)
                    .getAccessToken({
                        allowSignInPrompt: true,
                        forMSGraphAccess: false,
                    })
                    .then((token: string) => {
                        console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
                        resolve(token);
                    })
                    .catch((error: any) => {
                        console.log("cccccccccccccccccc");
```

The office.js I am using is this one.  Today using the debug version does not help.

```
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js
```

Extract from manifest

```xml
        <WebApplicationInfo>
            <Id>b8da6d8c-c134-47ba-9a63-891e048b8b8a</Id>
            <Resource>api://mfcm.xyz/b8da6d8c-c134-47ba-9a63-891e048b8b8a</Resource>
            <Scopes>
                <Scope>Sites.ReadWrite.All</Scope>
                <Scope>user.read</Scope>
                <Scope>files.read</Scope>
                <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
                <Scope>profile</Scope>
                <Scope>openid</Scope>
            </Scopes>
        </WebApplicationInfo>
```

Comment: David - can you share your manifest? Have you enabled the single sign on?

Comment: I am having issues reproing, could you provide additional information:
Are you trying to use getAccessToken on Win32, Mac, or Office Online?
What version of Office are you using? Is the 5001 error what you are seeing in the console? If that is the case, you need to use .catch on the Promise to get the error response. Can you give the URL of the office.js version that you have an issue with, and the beta version you are using without issue?